# How to get longest streak day and average day in Java / Groovy?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, groovy

I have problem with calculating longest streak day and average days from given Map>.

The code snippet presents as follow:

```
def testData = [:] as Map<Long, List<String>>;
testData[1L] = [
   "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-08", "2015-01-09",
   "2015-01-11", "2015-01-12", "2015-01-13", "2015-01-17"];
testData[2L] = [
   "2015-01-01", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-08",
   "2015-01-10", "2015-01-13", "2015-01-14"];

List results = [];
testData.each { kv ->

   // something to do here too..
   kv.value.each { dateInString ->
      // 1. convert string to date
      // 2. calculate average days
      // 3. calculate longest streak
   }

   results << [
     key: kv.key,
     longestStreak: 0 + " days",
     longestStreakDates: [
        [startDate: "", endDate: ""], [more..]
     ],
     averageDay: 0 + " days"
   ]
}

results.each { it ->
   println "${it.key} | Longest streak: ${it.longestStreak} | Average Day: ${it.averageDay}";
   println "Longest streak dates:";
   it.longestStreakDates.eachWithIndex { dateStreak, index ->
       println "\t\t${index}. ${dateStreak.startDate} - ${dateStreak.endDate}";
   }
}
```

Average day calculation for the **first** key id: 1. Average Day: (3 days + 2 days + 3 days + 1 day) / 4 (num of streak days) = 9 days/4 = 2.25 days

Average day calculation for the **second** key id: 2. Average Day: (1 day + 2 days + 1 day + 1 day + 2 days) / 5 (num of streak days) = 7 days/5 = 1.4 days

Longest Streak calculation please see http://www.quora.com/What-is-your-longest-streak-on-GitHub

The above snippet will eventually print like this:

```
1 | Longest streak: 3 days | Average Day: 2.25 days.
Longest streak dates:
     1. 2015-01-02 - 2015-01-04
2 | Longest streak: 2 days | Average Day: 1.4 days.
Longest streak dates:
     1. 2015-01-03 - 2015-01-04
     2. 2015-01-13 - 2015-01-14
```

Can anybody help me to implement the logic inside each loop "Something to do here too.."? Am I using the data model being far too complex or difficult to implement? if anybody has better and efficient way to tackle this problem let me know..

In addition, I may also need the "mode" and "median" calculation apart from the "average" calculation.

Thank you.

Comment: I've misunderstood what the longest streak is, sorry :) But will try in a moment.

Comment: Ok, added the answer. Hope it works correctly now.

Comment: @Opal you are rock! just saved my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go:

```
import java.util.Calendar

def testData = [
    1L:[
       "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-08", "2015-01-09",
       "2015-01-11", "2015-01-12", "2015-01-13", "2015-01-17"
    ],
    2L:[
       "2015-01-01", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-08",
       "2015-01-10", "2015-01-13", "2015-01-14"
    ]
]
testData.each { k, v ->
    def daysOfYear = v.collect { d -> Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', d) }.sort().collect { it[Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR] }
    //println(daysOfYear)
    def streaks = [:]
    def streakIdx = 0
    def streakCnt = 1
    for(int i = 0; i < daysOfYear.size(); i++) {
        if(daysOfYear[i] + 1 == daysOfYear[i+1]) {
            streakCnt++
        } else {
           streaks[streakIdx++] = streakCnt
           streakCnt = 1 
        }
    }
    def max = streaks.values().max()
    def avg = streaks.values().sum() / streaks.values().size()
    println("Key: $k, max: $max, avg: $avg")
}
```

Comment: The longest streak day is just like the github calculation..  You can see: http://www.quora.com/What-is-your-longest-streak-on-GitHub

Comment: maybe can be optimized without using java calendar import, can we just use pure groovy sugar syntax for this?

Comment: Probably it can. Feel free to edit the answer as far as it works :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution:

```
def testData = [
    1L:[
       "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-08", "2015-01-09",
       "2015-01-11", "2015-01-12", "2015-01-13", "2015-01-17"
    ],
    2L:[
       "2015-01-01", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-08",
       "2015-01-10", "2015-01-13", "2015-01-14"
    ]
]
testData.each { key, values ->
    def clumped = values.collect { Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', it) }
          .sort()
          .inject([[]]) { list, date ->
              if(list[0] != [] && list[0][0] != date - 1) {
                  list.add(0, [date])
              }
              else {
                 list[0].add(0, date)
              }
              list
          }
    println "Key $key, Max: ${clumped*.size().max()}, Avg: ${clumped*.size().sum() / clumped.size()}"
}
```

Comment: could you please help me to answer this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854113/groovy-aggregating-and-modelling-data-from-complex-nested-maps